# net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED ionic 4

Tags: android, cordova, http, ionic4

I'm writing a streaming application on ionic4, I'm testing it on my phone, but my it won't open the http links...

Console:

```
GET http://131.173.8.23/mjpg/video.mjpg
```

> net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED

I read you can get around that adding a `network_security_config.xml` file, but what do you know... it doesn't work! (but works fine on my browser)

Anybody got any idea ?

My code:

(network_security_config.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost:8100</domain>
        <domain>131.173.8.23:80</domain>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

(AndroidManifest)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest 
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true" 
    android:versionCode="1" 
    android:versionName="0.0.1" 
    package="io.ionic.starter" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application 
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:label="Simple Audio Stream" android:name="com.hutchind.cordova.plugins.streamingmedia.SimpleAudioStream" />
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:label="Simple Video Stream" android:name="com.hutchind.cordova.plugins.streamingmedia.SimpleVideoStream" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

(home.page.html)

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      CameraLux
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <video width="250" height="160" (click)="startVideo()" autoplay>
          <source src="http://131.173.8.23:80/mjpg/video.mjpg"/>
        </video>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <video width="250" height="160" autoplay>
          <source src="https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4"/>
        </video>
      </ion-col>
     <ion-col>
        <video width="250" height="160" (click)="startVideo()" autoplay>
          <source src="https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4"/>
        </video>
      </ion-col>            
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <video width="250" height="160" (click)="startVideo()" autoplay>
          <source src="https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4"/>
        </video>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <video width="250" height="160" (click)="startVideo()" autoplay>
         <source src="https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4"/>
        </video>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <video width="250" height="160" (click)="startVideo()" autoplay>
          <source src="https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4"/>
        </video>
      </ion-col>            
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

does not work well with `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

so in your config.xml should only have

```
  <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        </edit-config>
```

not both

Comment: hi thank you for the response, unfortunately this dosent change anything, i've already tried and i still got a ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED error :/

Comment: @delouisiano did u confirm that `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"`  is not present on your manifest.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
</edit-config>
```

config.xml run 
`cordova platform rm android` 
then 
`cordova platform add android`

Comment: It would be better to include all necessary input in here rather than relate to other's post.